# I can't get MotionEvent on emulator

Tags: android

Im trying to implement zoom to my application, but for some reason i can't get motion event.

```
public class GraphTest extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("MAIN","Created   ");
        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.i("MAIN","Touch");
        return false;
    }


}
```

here is my sample code, coud any one tell me what i missed? 
(currently i'm running it on emulated Android 4.1)
small update,
it did't work on emulated 2.3.3 and on phone with 2.3.5 as well

Comment: Have you set the onTouchListener anywhere? Can't see it here, is it set in your DrawView?

Comment: actually i forgot to set it:) thanks for pointing that